# Increase an int by one

Tags: c#

On another page I've said that `nr = 0`

```
var number = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["nr"];
int Nr = Convert.ToInt16(number);
```

And this works, `Nr = 0`

Now I want to upgrade Nr by one:

```
int next = Nr++;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work... `next = 0` too, but it supposed to be `1`.

Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you want `int next = ++Nr;` or `int next = Nr + 1;`

Comment: Nr++ doesn't return the incremented value.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How are you checking the value?
If you are checking the value of next while debugging, inspect the variable after you are done executing int next = Nr++ statement.

Comment: Okay. I meant it will not return the incremented value...

Answer (score 8):

`Nr++` increments and returns the *original* value of `Nr`.

`++Nr` increments and returns the *new* value of `Nr`.  So what you want is:

```
int next = ++Nr;
```

Answer (score 3):

In C# (or C++), the statement

```
int next = Nr++;
```

translates to, "assign the value of **Nr** to variable **next**, and then increment Nr by 1.

If you want Nr to increment first, your statement should look like this:

```
int next = ++Nr;
```

Here is the definition of the ++ operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx

Answer (score 0):

the problem is ...`Nr` is incremented after `Nr` set to `next` use `next=Nr+1;`

Comment: This doesn't address the real problem (the difference between i++ and ++i).

Answer (score 0):

There are two increment operators - pre-increment `++c` and post-increment `c++`.

`var x = ++c;` is equivalent to

```
c = c + 1;
var x = c;
```

while `var x = c++;` is equivalent to

```
var x = c;
c = c + 1;
```

and therefore `x` either receives the value before or after `c` got incremented.